# how to define a style positioning a node based on its size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

When we want to create a node whose position depends on its size, we may

- typeset this node in a box;
- gain the size information;
- discard the box/node;
- calculate the proper position;
- typeset the node again with proper positioning.

For example (this is not the real-world problem, but demonstrates the complexity)

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \tikz{
        \draw(-4,4)--(0,0)--(4,4);
        \foreach\sometext in{short,medium text,looooooooooog text,extra super outstanding text}{
            \node[opacity=0,draw](X){\sometext};
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{X}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{X}{east}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\thewidthofthenode{\pgf@x}
            \node[above,draw]at(0,\thewidthofthenode pt/2){\sometext};
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even more complicated:

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \tikz{
        \draw(-4,4)foreach\i in{-19,...,20}{-|(.2*\i-.1,{abs(.2*\i)})};
        \foreach\sometext in{short,medium text,looooooooooog text,extra super outstanding text}{
            \node[opacity=0,draw](X){\sometext};
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{X}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{X}{east}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\thewidthofthenode{round(\pgf@x/28.45274/.4)*.4}
            \node[above,draw]at(0,\thewidthofthenode/2){\sometext};
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

The question is

**Can this be done by defining a style `smart positioning` such that the following code gives the same result as above?**

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        smart positioning/.style={
            % how to define this?
        }
    }
    \tikz{
        \draw(-4,4)--(0,0)--(4,4);
        %\draw(-4,4)foreach\i in{-19,...,20}{-|(.2*\i-.1,{abs(.2*\i)})};
        \foreach\sometext in{short,medium text,looooooooooog text,extra super outstanding text}{
            \node[smart positioning,draw]{\sometext};
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

P.S. an answer that redefines some internal macros (e.g. `\pgfmultipartnode`) is appreciated. However, please do not modify the `\tikz{...}` part. The real-world problem involves some implicitly/deeply constructed nodes.

Comment: You could do it with a shape.  Each node has access to `\pgfnodeparttextbox` which is used to set the `text` anchor at the lower left corner.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a low level solution, and I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for, but it works in your particular example ... with a "small" difference that I use `smart positioning={draw=red}` in place of `smart positioning, draw=red`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  smart positioning/.style={
    overlay,opacity=0,draw=none,fill=none,
    append after command = {
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{east}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\thewidthofthenode{round(\pgf@x/28.45274/.4)*.4}
      }
      node[above,#1] at (0,\thewidthofthenode/2) {\sometext}
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \tikz{
    \draw(-4,4)foreach\i in{-19,...,20}{-|(.2*\i-.1,{abs(.2*\i)})};
    \foreach\sometext in{short,medium text,looooooooooog text,extra super outstanding text}{
      \node[smart positioning={draw=red}]{\sometext};
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]